# How to read all information from shell command in VBA and save it in .txt file

Tags: vba, excel

I try to use this code:

```
Shell(nppPath & " " & fileToOpen, vbNormalFocus)
```

which opens txt file `nppPath = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"` but I cannot read from it and save it as .txt file using VBA.

Looking forward to any suggestions.

Comment: Ignoring NotePad completely for a moment.. are you trying to create a text file, or are you trying to read one?

Comment: I am trying to create txt file from shell information

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by *shell information*? Do you mean the output of a shell command, such as DIR - perhaps piped into a text file?

Comment: Sorry, yes, what I meant to say is that I want to copy the output of shell command and paste it to new text file or something like that

Comment: Okay, so what shell command are you running to create the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm presuming you copied the nppPath over wrong as it should be

```
nppPath = "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
```

but for reading from the text file you could use free file:

```
Dim IntFile As Integer, StrFileName As String, StrFileContent As String

StrFileName = fileToOpen 'Your file location here
IntFile = FreeFile
Open StrFileName For Input As #IntFile
    StrFileContent = Input(LOF(IntFile), IntFile) 'This now contains the text
Close #IntFile
```

This will read the text file into a single variable that you can then use however you wish.
If you want to write to a text file you can use the following code:

```
Dim StrNewLocation As String, StrFileContent As String

StrNewLocation = "" 'Put the new files name and location here
StrFileContent = "Example" 'The text to go into the new file

Open StrNewLocation For Output As #1
    Write #1, StrFileContent
Close #1
```

Hopefully this helps you solve your problem if not send me a message and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: If you're invoking Notepad using Shell, you don't actually need the path at all. Shell knows where to find Notepad.

Comment: On Open StrNewLocation For Output As #1 i have Path/File access error (run time error 75)

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any other issues.